# Using RelativeLayout, LinearLayout and layout_weight at the same time - weird behaviour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I've got an activity layout specified in an XML file - **activity_intro.xml** - and I'm trying to create another one that is similar but slightly different - that's going to be **activity_instructions.xml**.

The Intro activity has a 9patch image at the bottom of the screen that is supposed to stay there and only adjust to different widths of the screens.
The Instructions activity is supposed to contain the same image but above 2 more buttons - all  three of these views need to be always located at the bottom of the screen.

activity_intro.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/home_background" >

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/Activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/introAnimationImageView"
                android:layout_width="152dip"
                android:layout_height="176dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/intro_animation_content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/animation_intro01" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/introTextViewTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/intro_title"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/introTextViewSubtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/intro_subtitle"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/introButtonLoginSignup"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="@string/intro_button_label_login_signup" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/introButtonInstructions"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/introButtonLoginSignup"
                    android:text="@string/intro_button_label_instructions" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/introButtonReportAnonymously"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/introButtonLoginSignup"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="@string/intro_button_label_report_anonymously" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/footer_cityscape" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image]

Since I've got working code for Intro, I wanted to make Instructions follow its example but the layout_weight property isn't behaving as expected. First of all, I was only trying to put in the 2 buttons and leave out the image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/home_background" >

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/Activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/instructionsTextViewTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/instructions_title_1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/instructionsImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/instructions_image_content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/forms" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/instructionsTextViewDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/instructions_description_1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/instructionsButtonPrevious"
            style="@style/ButtonPrevious"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/instructions_button_label_previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/instructionsButtonNext"
            style="@style/ButtonNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/instructions_button_label_next" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This only worked when I set the layout_weight of the bottom RelativeLayout to 1 (instead of 0) and for the ScrollView 0.1 (instead of 1). If I used the original values the RelativeLayout would take up all the screen. Could anyone explain to me why that is?
I also tried googling the issue and noticed people would suggest to set layout_height to 0dip which I tried but it also didn't work as expected.

Secondly, I tried adding the already mentioned ImageView to the bottom RelativeLayout. This, however, basically displays only the ImageView and not the buttons - or one of the buttons is on top of the image (hiding it). Why is that? Don't I specifically set the buttons to be placed below it?
[image]

What should the code look like in order for it to be doing what I expect it?

Further explanation:

Below are images that should help indicate what exactly I want to achieve. The green bits are the ScrollViews - I added them because Android devices tend to have diverse screen sizes. Their purpose is to present the content properly independently of the screen size, i.e. if the screen is small, the user will be able to scroll that part to read the entire text and view the image.
The red bit on the left (Intro) shows the ImageView that is supposed to always be at the bottom of the screen; it'll always be there, visible, and it's the green bit above it that will be movable.
If you take a look at the red bit on the right (Instructions), there's a Next button that's covering the image with the lorry/truck that was visible in the Intro screenshot. Now that's wrong - there should be 2 buttons BELOW the image, as seen on the last screenshot (the 2 blue rectangles).

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: In generally, when you're working with `layout_weight` you'd set to `0` the dimension on the axis you would want the weight to be applied(so your `ScrollView` will use a height of `0`). It's hard to tell what you're doing, regarding the last image, without seeing the layout. Try this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/8318505

Comment: Maybe, you mean **0dp**. Try.

Comment: I added some more explanation with screenshots guys - please see if that's of any help.